# Can I get iterators from an ArrayList in multiple threads and use all of them safelly?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I have an ArrayList instance that is shared by multiple threads. It's gets initialized in a synchronized block (so there is a memory barrier to make it visible to all threads) and all threads only read from it. The ArrayList never changes.

I've read lots of posts online but it's still not clear to me if it's safe to read no matter how I do the read. If I get an iterator from it in each thread do the iterators share some state that gets altered while iterating etc. I'm not sharing the iterators, each thread gets it's own.

Is it thread safe for reads, no matter how I do the read?

Comment: Read-only is always thread-safe. Sharing iterators is probably not thread-safe, as each iterator has state and reading from an iterator changes that state, but if each thread has its own iterator it's probably OK.

Comment: @user3580294: `...it's probably OK...` is why I'm asking this. Is it for sure or probably OK? :)

Comment: Oh fine, it's definitely OK. As long as you aren't sharing changing state and aren't altering shared state, you're OK. So just don't use `Iterator#remove()`.

Comment: If each thread has its own iterator its okay. You can't share a single iterator between threads however

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as each thread has its own iterator, then you are OK.

The only time you need to worry about synchronization is when one thread is modifying (writing) a shared data structure while others are reading from it. This can lead to the data-structure being in an inconsistent state (imagine the thread wasn't finished its modifications when all of a sudden the scheduler [pre-empts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) it/switches to another thread).

When all threads are only reading, the data will never be in an inconsistent state, and you don't need to worry about thread synchronization.

Comment: Does that hold for any king of collection? Reading it, in whatever way you like is always safe?

Comment: Yes, this applies to any collection/data-structure.

Answer (score 0):

As long as iterators are used to read only this will work as expected.Also an iterator is fail-fast because it may throws a ConcurrentModificationException due to following reasons:

1. In multithreaded processing, if one thread is trying to modify a
   Collection while another thread is iterating over it.
2. In single-threaded or in multithreaded, if after the creation of the
   Iterator, the collection is modified using its own methods rather
   using the Iterator's own methods.